# intersect two lists with same object but diffrent variables

Tags: c#

I have two lists from this object

```
class ObjA
{ 
  int id
  string name
}
```

### list1 example:

1  foo1

2  foo2

3  foo3

4  foo4

5  foo5

### list2 example:

3  foo1

5  foo3

2  foo5

i want to do somthing like this:

```
list<objA> intersect = list1.Select(a => a.name).Intersect(list2.Select(b => b.name));
```

but I want the result to be:

### result:

1  foo1

3  foo3

5  foo5

(the full content of first list)

what am I missing?

Comment: So, you want there to be empty instances present in your list, so that the indexing would remain same?

Comment: Yes. I want to get the full object from list 1, while intersecting only the names.

Comment: @D.Petrov I think by "the full content of first list" the OP means they want the `objA` objects and not just the `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either override `Equals` (and `GetHashCode`) on `ObjA` to define "equality" as "having the same name", create a class that implements `IEqualityComparer<ObjA>` using the same rules, or just use a different Linq query:

```
List<ObjA> intersect = list1.Where(x => list2.Any(y => y.name == x.Name)).ToList();
```

Comment: If you can edit. I used your solution with a small edit.

List <objA> intersect1 = list1.Where(x => list2.Any(y => y.name == x.name)).ToList();

Comment: @Yogi_Bear Well, it doesn't change anything, but I made that change.

Comment: I actually ment for the list<objA> part, but ok

Comment: @Yogi_Bear OK I see that now.  You also need `ToList()` at the end in that case.

Answer (score -1):

You could do

```
var interset = list1.Where(a => list2.Any(b => a.name = b.name)).ToList();
```

If the lists could be large you might want to make a lookup from the second list

```
var lookup = list2.ToLookup(x => x.name);
var insterset = list1.Where(a => lookup.Contains(a.name));
```

Or maybe just a `HashSet` of the names

```
var lookup = new HashSet<string>(list2.Select(x => x.name));
var insterset = list1.Where(a => lookup.Contains(a.name));
```